# 100% usage on few core while few core are 100% idle

Tags: cpu-load

Getting below CPU usage output. What could be issue that few core is 100% used while few core are 100% idle:

```
Cpu0  :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  : 99.7%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu4  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu5  :100.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu6  : 99.7%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu7  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu8  : 99.7%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu9  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
```

Comment: It depends on what you are running. Why did you use both 12.04 and 14.04 tags? I don’t think this happens on two OSes at once.

Comment: First thing to do if you're still using 12.04 is install a supported version.  End Of Life versions are off topic here, and this question will be closed soon.

Comment: @ZeissIkon OP side-stepped the issue by removing **12.04** tag forcing me to retract my close vote.

Comment: This is just a normal behaviour. Why do you think, the load should be evenly distributed?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I don't have close votes yet on this SE, but it also makes sense this wouldn't be version dependent.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't clear as to whether you want to know why all cores are not being utilized, or why you have some at 100%.

An application determines how many cores or threads it will use.  Most applications are single threaded and will only use one core.  This is so that all operations happen in order as expected.  For instance if a+b=c and c+d=e are passed to 2 different cores, how would you know what c is when processing c+d=e if a+b=c hasn't completed?

You can use the `top` command to view which applications are using these cores.

Answer (score 1):

The way I read your included report, you're getting 100% usage on all cores -- just only some are on "user" tasks, others are running "system" tasks or something else (whatever "id" is).  This is normal, due to the single-thread nature of most tasks (as noted in another answer).  The computer is doing some work in the foreground, stuff you explicitly initiated, and some in the background (OS tasks, usually, though it could also be things like BOINC tasks or other distributed computing systems).

Comment: Doesn’t `id` stand for _idle_? In this case, your explanation does not work fully. However, I agree that the most important thing is the single-thread nature of the running tasks.